# How to show php responsed data in html table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to getting a .json file from another  server and want to show .json file in a html table. php code is successfully  returning json. But my problem is that i want to view this in a table because i am not able to implement php result in javascript when i will click on button named Get Data

Here is my .php file

```
<html>
<header>
    <title>Hello
    </title>
    </header>
<body>


<!--javascript make append table data-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<script>

    $(function() {



   $.getJSON('$result.json', function(data) {
       $.each(data.videoLectureListing, function(i, f) {
          var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.Id + "</td>" +
           "<td>" + f.videoName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.date + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.time + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.video + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.image + "</td>" +
           "<td>" + f.videoDuration + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.liveStatus + "</td>" + "<td>"+ "</tr>"
           $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
     });

   });

});
</script>




<!--javascript  append table data ended -->


<!-- user form -->
<form method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='formSubmitted' value=1>

    <label for="userId"><b>UserId</b></label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Your User Id" name="userId" autofocus required>

    <label for="categoryId"><b>categoryId</b></label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter categoryId" name="categoryId" required>

    <button type="submit" >GET DATA</button>
</form>
<!-- user form -->



<!--table-->

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
   <table id= "userdata" width="100%" border="5">
  <thead>
            <th>VIDEO NAME</th>
            <th>DATE</th>
            <th>TIME</th>
            <th>DURACTION</th>
            <th>LINK </th>
        </thead>
      <tbody>

       </tbody>
   </table>

</div>
</div>

<!--table data end-->



<!---php file start-->
<?php

$userId = $_POST['userId'];
$categoryId = $_POST['categoryId'];

if (isset($_POST['formSubmitted'])) {

$url = 'https://www.otherserver.php';
$data = array('userId' => $userId, 'categoryId' => $categoryId);

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }

echo ($result);
//json_encode($result, true);
}
?>


<!---php file ended    


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not at all clear what specific problem is here

Comment: problem is that when i am clicking on button it showing a json data but i want to append it into table.But i knot know how to do that

Comment: php code ia working fine and returning json raw data but i want to decorate it

Comment: please look javascript once

Comment: Are you asking how to do this when button gets clicked and not when page loads as shown? Question is still very vague

Comment: That really doesn't help understand what your specific problem is. You will need to explain it in more detail

Comment: sir suppose user fill data in form it go to >php code > another server > return json data > use this data in javascript > show in a table format

Comment: Use a form submit event listener. Look for tutorials on how to use ajax and forms

Comment: sir if you want to help me please edit my code and paste in answer section so that it give best results.Thanks

Comment: You really need to do the basic research first yourself. Using forms and ajax together is extremely common and you will have no problems finding lots of tutorials on the subject. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: sir if there is a 2 or 3 line correction because my javascript is not getting data from php output that ia major problem

Comment: You have an Ajax call. And you have a form. The two things appear to not be connected. Which bit is giving you trouble? Are you getting JavaScript errors? Or some other issue. Instead of asking "how to"...please explain the specific **problem** occurring in the code you have written already. We don't know exactly which part of the process is giving you difficulty

Comment: In Java script at the place of ```$.getJSON('$result.json' ```   I  saved a``` .json``` on ```local host ```and and  name it ```videodata.json``` and then update    ```$.getJSON('videodata.json'  ```and it working. But now what i am trying is that i created a ```php ```which take request on a another server on internet and fetch data from other server. Now``` php code``is returning data successfully but ```Ajax``` is failed. I don't know why

Comment: If it failed then you need to look at the error messages, there is likely to be a clue there. Have you checked your Developer Tools? Especially the Console and Network tools?

Comment: please modify my php code so rhat it will return json text like a .json file

Comment: Look if you aren't going to give the information that people are asking for then it's really not very easy to help you. We need to know your specific problem. Did you understand what I asked you to do in order to check for errors?

Answer (score -1):

Please add **action** attribute in the form tag.

```
<!-- user form -->
    <form method='POST' action='php_file_path'>
        <input type='hidden' name='formSubmitted' value=1>

        <label for="userId"><b>UserId</b></label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Your User Id" name="userId" autofocus required>

        <label for="categoryId"><b>categoryId</b></label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Enter categoryId" name="categoryId" required>

        <button type="submit" >GET DATA</button>
    </form>
    <!-- user form -->
```

Comment: Action is not needed if the form should post back to the same URL